# using resolve in app.config

Tags: angularjs, app-config, angular-promise, resolve

I'm using angularjs's resolve in config to load some values needed for my controller, before controller is loaded. This is the code I'm using to test my logic

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("lab1App", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/views/view1.html"
        }).when("/view2", {
            templateUrl: "views/view2.html",
            controller: "SecondController",
            resolve: {
                name: ["DropdownService", function (dropDownSvc) {
                    return dropDownSvc.loadName(5);
                }]
            }
        }).otherwise({
            template: "Don't have any routes associated with this"
        });
    }]);

    app.controller("MainController", [ "$scope", function ($scope) {

    }]);

    app.controller("SecondController", [ "$scope", "name", function ($scope, name) {
        console.log(name);
    }]);

    app.constant("API", { url: "http://localhost:55339/api/dropDowns" });

    app.factory("DropdownService", ["API", "$http", "$q", function (api, $http, $q) {

        return {
            loadName: function (id) {
                console.log("im here");
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http.get(api.url + "/" + id)
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    }).error(function (err, status) {
                        deferred.reject("Error: " + err + ", Status: " + status);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }]);

})();
```

now when I run the code I'm getting this error:

> *Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nameProvider <- name <- SecondController*

Although I'm getting the name variable in the controller, the error is being thrown.

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did the answer below address your question?

Comment: no- I tried removing it from the view2.html, but still getting the error

Comment: This error means that you are instantiating a `SecondController` controller with `ng-controller` (or anywhere else) **in addition to** the route configuration. That second instantiation doesn't have the injectable `name`. This is your code that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/ADJyT4WtQpUR2LH9rvwg?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess that somewhere, likely inside `view2.html`, you have

```
ng-controller="SecondController"
```

This second invocation of `"SecondController"` controller is what throws the "unknown provider" error, because it doesn't have the `resolve`-d `name`.

To fix, remove the `ng-controller` directive.